# Setting filepath to reference a file at the root of the Solution or Project

Tags: c#

I want someone to just be able to fire up my solution, and in the Program have it run and just put this csv at the root of the project for example so that it just picks it up in my method that's gonna read this csv file.

```
File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(a => a.Split(';'));
```

Problem is, not sure how to get this so that if someone copies my solution to their c drive, what this filepath should look like..I want them to be able to fire this solution up, run the console app, and since this file is already in the same directory as my project, just want to basically hard code the filename via constant and not worry about ok, where is this file..it's always gonna be here after they copy it for testing purposes.

So what should I do, include the .csv in my .net project then just make the constant "filename.csv"?  I tried that, does not work.

I end up with this which fails:

```
 File.ReadLines("someFile.csv").Select(a => a.Split(';'));
```

and I've included that file in my project...the main console project where the program is running from.

here's my solution structure

```
SomeTest (.NET solution and it's the root solution folder)
    SomeTest (console project)
       Constants.cs
    SomeTest.BL
    SomeTest.DL
       filename.csv
```

I've moved the actual csv to my DL as I'm using it as the test data source.

So when they copy my SomeTest solution folder down to their c drive, wherever they put it, I need that constant to read `C:\\root path to wherever they copied SomeTest folder to\\SomeTest.DL\\filename.csv`  see what I mean? I need to hard code the SomeTest.DL after the root path..but I just can't get the root path, in my case C:\www and grab that part and then I'll append for example the \SomeTest.DL\filename.csv" string to it.

Comment: Pass the filename as a command line argument to your program? What exactly does not work?

Comment: when I run it it tries to look for that csv file under 'C:\www\SomeTest\SomeTest\bin\Debug\Commands.csv'.

Comment: so you want to embed the .csv in your project?

Comment: can you not just use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` ?

Comment: Okay so you want to get the folder that the program is currently executing from?

Comment: Have a look at the `CodeBase` property of `Assembly`.  You should be able to get the full path of the executing code and work from there.

Comment: when I try Environment.CurrentDirectory, it's for some reason appending like 2 paths meaning it includes an adde bin path:   Environment.CurrentDirectory "C:\\www\\SomeTest\\SomeTest\\bin\\Debug" so it's appending \\SomeTest\\bin\\Debug for some odd reason.

Comment: so your looking for `C:\\www\\SomeTest\\SomeTest` ??

Comment: "so you want to embed the .csv in your project?" yes

Comment: "Okay so you want to get the folder that the program is currently executing from?" yes OR I could get it from some other folder within the solution like a datalayer project within the solution.  Either way I need to be able to reference the full path to that csv in whatever project it's included in.

Comment: "so your looking for C:\\www\\SomeTest\\SomeTest" right..

Comment: and remember wherever they copy my SomeTest solution folder is up to them...so it may not be C:\www it could be C:\\, C:\\SomeFolder\ or whatever.  The point is I need my constant to pick up my csv that's already contained withing a folder in SomeTest solution...and it needs to append the prevfix or whatever you call it, the "c:\\.."

Comment: please see updates to my original post, I added more clarification including my solution structure.

Answer (score 3):

I think the safest option is to add the csv file to your project and set its `BuildAction` to None and set `Copy To Output Directory` to copy.

[image]

Then users can always access using `File.ReadLines("MyDataCsv.csv")`, plus you can view/edit the csv from the Visual Studio IDE which I assume the other programmers will want.

Comment: close, only problem is it's taking the relative path.  So I end up with for example SomeTest\\ instead of c:\\www\SomeTest

Comment: so they'll be getting my solution folder, copying it down to their hard drive.  Who knows where they copy it to.  I have mine inside C:\www\ but they could have it in the root of C, or wherever.  I want this program to run and them not to have to worry about changing this filepath string.  It should just find itself in whatever project, like the main console project...it knows what the root filepath is before the folder of the solution ...appends that to the filepath automatically..I think we're all understanding this is what I want right?  yours is close just doesn't append the root path

Comment: strange... on my pc it returns the root path.

Comment: ok I had a path.combine around it, probably causing the issue.

Comment: Now here's the thing.  I moved my constant out of my main project like yours above to my DL project but it's still spitting out like yours, the path to the main program project...if I move the constants file with that logic to another layer, it should be able to see that via the Getparent and getcurrentdirectory but it looks like both are still refing the main project.

Comment: here we go, but there's got to be an existing method to get something like this:  Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName.  I had to add another .Parent to walk backwards one more to produce just the root path to my solution folder so I now get "C:\\www\\SomeTest" which I can work with now.  But there has to be a way without having to do all these nested .Parent

Comment: added perhaps something thats cleaner

Comment: But I dont think this sovles your problem because what if the user sets there debug folder somewhere out of the project directory, then none of these solutions will work because it bases the directory on where the application is running not where your project is.

Comment: Updated with the only failsafe way to do this.